# Pivotal gemfire load testing

Tags: java, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

How to test pivotal gemfire with more than 4000 concurrent users inserting data into gemfire region and same number of concurrent users reading data from gemfire region.
Reading of data from gemfire region can happen after the insertion operation or parallel.
Can you please suggest some best solution around it.

Comment: By "user", I assume you mean some application producing and consuming data to/from GemFire; if so, have a look at JMeter (http://jmeter.apache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit ambiguous.

If you're looking at purely benchmarking GemFire then the YCSB framework would be a good place to start as it provides standardized tests across various IMDG and RDBM systems.

If you are looking for tools for your own app then I'd suggest looking at Jmeter. You'll obviously need to provide some custom code in order to do puts and gets but it will provide you with many other capabilities such as being able to scale your test and also quantify the results.

If you're looking for suggestions on a GemFire architecture to support the scale of your test then you'll need to provide more details as to the functional and non-functional requirements of your application.